# How to ask WSL to check if the distribution exists, using Bash and `wsl.exe`?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to ask WSL to check if the distribution exists or doesn't exist, for example, `wsl.exe -l -v` outputs:

```
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
  Arch-Linux             Running         2
* Ubuntu                 Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
```

I need to ask WSL to check if `desktop-desktop-data` or `Arch` exists.

Here is my small Bash code. I tested with several different ways, nothing worked.

```bash
# Distribution name: Ubuntu
wsl_distro_name="docker-desktop"

# WSL command to find the distribution name
wsl_command=`wsl.exe -l -v | grep -iq '^$wsl_distro_name' | awk '{print $2}'`

if [[ "$wsl_command" ]]; then
    echo "Distro found"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Not found"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: If you run your script with `-x` turned on, your will spot the problem immedately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Updated answer*:

The core issue behind this question has been fixed, or at least improved, in the latest WSL Preview release ([0.64.0](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases/tag/0.64.0)), but note that this is currently only available for Windows 11 users.

To avoid breaking older code that relies on (or works around) the issue, the fix is opt-in.  Setting a `WSL_UTF8` environment variable with a value of `1` (and only, in my testing, that value) will result in correct/expected output from `wsl.exe`.

Note that if using this environment variable *inside* WSL, you'll need to also add it to `WSLENV` so that it gets passed "back" to Windows through Interop.

For your use, for example, the following will now work:

```bash
export WSL_UTF8=1
WSLENV="$WSLENV":WSL_UTF8

wsl_distro_name="docker-desktop-data"
wsl.exe -l -v | grep -q "\s${wsl_distro_name}\s" && echo "Found" || echo "Not found"f
```

##### For older WSL installations

*Short answer:*

```
wsl_distro_name="docker-desktop-data"
wsl.exe -l -v | iconv -f UTF-16 | grep -q "\s${wsl_distro_name}\s" && echo "Found" || echo "Not found"
```

*Explanation*:

There are a few things going on with your example:

- First, the thing that probably has you stymied the most is a WSL bug (covered in more detail in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72323974/11810933)) that causes the output to be in a mangled UTF-16 encoding.  You can see this to some degree with `wsl.exe | hexdump -C`, which will show the null byte characters after every regular character.

  The solution to that part is to run it through `iconv -f utf16`.  For example:

  ```
  wsl.exe -l -v | iconv -f UTF-16
  ```

I'm guessing you probably introduced some of the following errors into your code while trying to work around the preceding bug:

- You have `$wsl_distro_name` in single quotes in your `grep`, which disables string interpolation in Bash.  You need double-quotes there.
- The `^` won't work at the beginning of the regex since there is whitespace (and/or an asterisk) in the first couple of characters of the `wsl.exe -l -v` output.  Better to use `"\s$wsl_distro_name\s` to find the distro name that is surrounded by whitespace.

  This will also prevent the expression from finding a "partial" distribution name.  Without it, "docker-desktop" would match both "docker-desktop" *and/or* "docker-desktop-data".
- `grep -q` disables output and only returns a status code of `0` when found or `1` if not.  Since you are attempting to capture the grep output into `$wsl_command`, the result will always be empty.  You either remove the `-q` to capture the output or continue to use `-q` and test the status code.
- Given your `if` statement, it seems like you may be expecting the output to be a status result anyway, but testing `"$wsl_command"` won't work for that, nor will capturing the output via backticks.  That would look more like:

  ```
  wsl_distro_name="docker-desktop-data"
  wsl.exe -l -v | iconv -f UTF-16 | grep -q "\s${wsl_distro_name}\s"
  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
      echo Found
  fi
  ```

  The `$?` variable holds the exit code of the last command.

  Alternatively:

  ```
  wsl_distro_name="docker-desktop-data"
  wsl_distro_result=$(wsl.exe -l -v | iconv -f UTF-16 | grep -o "\s${wsl_distro_name}\s.*" | awk '{print $2}')
  if [[ -n "$wsl_distro_result" ]]; then
      echo "Found ${wsl_distro_name} and it is ${wsl_distro_result}."
  else
      echo "${wsl_distro_name} not found."
  fi
  ```

  Note that I added the `-o` option to `grep` in that snippet.  The default distribution will have an asterisk in the first field, which means that we need to "normalize" it so that the second field for `awk` is always the Status.
- Finally, recommend using `$()` rather than backticks.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4708549/11810933), but note that the POSIX spec says, *"the backquoted variety of command substitution is not recommended."*
- Side note:  If for some reason you ever need to run this in Alpine, then make sure to install the `gnu-libiconv` package in order for `iconv` to handle this properly as well.

Comment: I don't understand how `\s` possibly can work in your code. You are requesting grep to use _simple regular expressions_, which means that \s matches a literal character `s`. For instance, `echo absc | grep  -o \s` matches exactly the _s_.

Comment: @user1934428 So it's a bit weird. It does work to match whitespace, but I should have read more closely when Googling/scanning last night when coming up with it. I use so many regex versions that I pretty much have to look up the details each time. I Googled, [grep whitespace](https://www.google.com/search?q=grep+whitespace), for which the top result is [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4233159/11810933). I saw the `\s`, tried it, and it worked. I didn't read further into the comments that it was reported as a bug, declined as not-a-bug, but never documented (to this day, AFAIK).

Comment: So maybe `[[:space:]]` would be better, but `\s` has worked for the last decade or so, and any version of `grep` in a WSL installation should be okay.

Comment: You **can** make \s work with grep. You just need the `-P` option. But of course [[:space:]] is preferable.

Comment: @user1934428 Oh, it works without `-P`.  I just retested it.  My question now would be why it matches *both* a literal `s` in your example but whitespace in mine.

Comment: @user1934428 And it turns out that when the expression is *quoted*, it matches whitespace, not the literal.  `echo "absc" | grep -o "\s"` does not match.  `echo "absc " | grep -o "\s"`  does match.  `echo "abc " | grep -o \s` does not match.  `echo "abc " | grep -o \s` does not match.  Same with single or double-quotes.

Comment: AFAICT, that's the *shell* changing the unquoted `\s` to a literal `s`, right?  E.g. `echo \s | grep "^s$"`

Comment: Git Bash and WSL don't recognise `utf16`. I switched for `UTF-16`. They recognised. Git Bast didn't find the distribution, but the inner WSL found it.

Comment: @GustavoReis Good to know.  `iconv -l` on Ubuntu shows both forms, but I can imagine that's a convenience that isn't available in all versions.  I'll update the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds : Correct. That's why I used quotes in my counter-example, `echo "absc  " | grep -o "\s"`. That is, _grep_ sees the backslash, but for grep, a backslash followed by a letter `s` does not have a special meaning. That's why the space after the string _absc_  is not matched. The input string would also have to contain a backslash, followed by a space, in order to match.

Comment: @user1934428 For me, the example you just provided (in quotes) **is** matched.  Unless you are using a very old grep, since the `\s` behavior was [changed in 2.6.3](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?30515) over a decade ago.