# Select-String does some really weird things

Tags: powershell

To determine if Debian is the default instance in wsl I tried to use `Select-String` to look for the `* Debian` expression in the output of `wsl --list --verbose` but some weird stuff is going on  here

```
$ wsl --list --verbose
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Debian    Stopped         2

$ wsl --list --verbose | Select-String "D"   

* Debian    Stopped         2
```

searching for "D" result is a bit weird but this is the expected behavior

but searching for "De" returns no result and this does not make sense at all

```
$ wsl --list --verbose | Select-String "De"
```

does anyone have a good explanation for this ?

edit:

findstr has the same result

```
$ wsl --list --verbose | findstr d     
* Debian    Stopped         2
$ wsl --list --verbose | findstr De
```

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64105040/15339544

Comment: The `wsl` executable is producing Unicode text. `wsl --list --verbose | Format-Hex | Out-String`